# jQuery Swipe Panels

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Mobile Application Development - The Influence of Touch and Gestures</title>
  <script>
    $(document).on("pagebeforeshow", ".assignment", function() {
      $(document).on("swipeleft swiperight", ".assignment", function(e) {
        if ($(".ui-page-active").jqmData("panel") !== "open") {
          if (e.type === "swipeleft") {
            $("#right-panel").panel("open");
          } else if (e.type === "swiperight") {
            $("#menu").panel("open");
          }
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Start of Home page -->
  <div data-role="page" id="home" data-title="Home" class="assignment">
    <div data-role="header" data-add-back-btn="true" class="ui-button-right" data-add-back-btn="true">
      <a href="#menu" data-role="button" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
      <a href="#home" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
      <h1>Mobile Application Development</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <h3>The Influence of Touch and Gestures on Mobile Device Usability</h3>
      <p>Below is some of the functionality that is possible with jQuery and how it can be used.</p>
      <a href="#section1" data-role="button">Section #1</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Overlay Menu -->
    <div data-role="panel" id="menu" data-display="overlay" data-position="left">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h2>Menu</h2>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content">
        <a href="#section1" data-role="button">Section #1</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End of Menu -->

    <div data-role="footer" id="footer">
      <p class="footerText">Ben Saunders</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End of  Page -->

  <!-- Start of Home page -->
  <div data-role="page" id="section1" data-title="Home" class="assignment">
    <div data-role="header" data-add-back-btn="true" class="ui-button-right" data-add-back-btn="true">
      <a href="#menu" data-role="button" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
      <a href="#home" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
      <h1>Section 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">

    </div>

    <!-- Overlay Menu -->
    <div data-role="panel" id="menu" data-display="overlay" data-position="left">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h2>Menu</h2>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content">
        <a href="#section1" data-role="button">Section #1</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End of Menu -->

    <div data-role="footer" id="footer">
      <p class="footerText">Ben Saunders</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End of  Page -->

</body>

</html>
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Using this code,

```
$( document ).on( "pagecreate", ".assignment", function() {
      $( document ).on( "swipeleft swiperight", ".assignment", function( e ) {
         if ( $( ".ui-page-active" ).jqmData( "panel" ) !== "open" ) {
            if ( e.type === "swipeleft" ) {
               $( "#right-panel" ).panel( "open" );
            } else if ( e.type === "swiperight" ) {
               $( "#menu" ).panel( "open" );
            }
         }
      });
   });
```

I am trying to use this for swipe menus in a jQuery all in one html page, small applications, but when I change to another page, the swipe animation to bring up the menu no longer works.

I have a feeling it could be the jQuery event but am not entirely lied up on the subject.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/u73hgLuy/

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: Full HTML has been added to the main post, thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to add a working example (code snippet), where we can see the problem? You can add it to your question, then we have everything to reproduce it and try to understand what might be wrong.

Comment: Added a JSFiddle link with it showing the problem, going to 'Section 1' will stop the menu from working, and swiping in from the left.

Comment: Is this part of a sample you could link to?

Comment: No, it is something that is being developed within a project I am doing that I cannot link to sorry.